# Retrieve a list of recipe data that store under user collection?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 collections in Firebase one is users collection where I have stored all user details, and another collection is colrecipe in it for each user there is a subcollection with recipe.uid as documents .I'm trying to get Firestore collections based on an array list.

How can I retrieve details of those recipes from users collections?

```
body: StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .document(globals.user.email)
      .collection('colrecipes')
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }

    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final DocumentSnapshot doc =
              snapshot.data!.documents[index];

               if ((recipemodel.recipeName)!.isEmpty) {
                      return Card(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          elevation: 20,
                          shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () => navigateToInfo(doc),
                            onTapDown: (details) => _getTapPosition(details),
                            onLongPress: () => _showContextMenu(context),
                            child: Container(
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Stack(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Container(
                                            height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .height *
                                                0.17,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              image: DecorationImage(
                                                image: NetworkImage(
                                                  '${doc["image"]}' +
                                                      '?alt=media&token',
                                                ),
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                            )),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 8, vertical: 6),
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.05,
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color:
                                            Color.fromARGB(146, 205, 204, 204),
                                      ),
                                      child: Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                        child: Text(
                                          doc["recipeName"],
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                            color:
                                                Color.fromARGB(255, 51, 44, 25),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize:
                                                displayWidth(context) * 0.050,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.06,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 98, 91, 94),
                                      ),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: [
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Transform.scale(
                                                scale: 1.4,
                                                child: Icon(
                                                  Icons.room_service,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                doc["recipeServe"],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize:
                                                      displayWidth(context) *
                                                          0.045,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Transform.scale(
                                                scale: 1.4,
                                                child: Icon(
                                                  Icons.access_time_filled,
                                                  color: Color.fromARGB(
                                                      255, 255, 255, 255),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                doc["recipeTimePrepared"],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize:
                                                      displayWidth(context) *
                                                          0.045,
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ));
                    }
                  }
```

[image: Firestore: The recipeIDs that store under specific user]
[image: Firestore: The recipe collection]

Comment: Please don't post the same problem multiple times. At best the repost will get closed, but it may get you banned from the site. If you have additional details, you can click the `edit` link under your original question to add those.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your colrecipes id in users is not a collection, do it a collection and name iit to `recipeIds`  then the below code will work after that
You need to update your stream like this

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(globals.user.email)
        .collection("recipeIds")
        .snapshots();
```

if you do not want to make a collection the update your code like this

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(globals.user.email)
            .get();
```

in your listview.builder use like this

```
ListView(
                  children:
                      snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data =
                        document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    return Text(data[recipeIds]);
                  }).toList(),
                );
```

Comment: But how can i retrieve the list without making it as a collection with other way？

Comment: I updated the answer please check that out

Comment: sorry, one more question, i trying to use the code that without make a collection.However, it cant suit with the streambuilder. can you help me to fit it and return the recipe based on index ?

Comment: try changeing the .get() to  .snapshots();

Comment: Still cannot fit too. This is the image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UwmI.png which return the error like this:
'Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'. Tried to infer 'DocumentSnapshot*' for 'T' which doesn't work: Parameter 'builder' declared as     'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<T>)' but argument is 'Widget Function(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>)'. The type 'DocumentSnapshot*' was inferred from: Parameter 'stream' declared as     'Stream<T>?' but argument is 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot*>*'. Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.'

Comment: I think it's a parsing issue in your code, try to print it on the console raw without parsing ,then you know your data is fetched